# correctly use aspect ratio aspect fill in iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, aspect-ratio

Aspect ratio **"Scale To Fill"** and **"Aspect Fit"** make the image stretched to whole UIImageView size. How can I use Aspect Fill" to handell UIImageView inside UITableViewCell. UIImageView inside UITableViewCell is running out of the screen in **Aspect Fill**. I want to make the image to **take is original size** rather then to stretch but I want to **prevent it form overlapping** over its lower cell. Rather its better if it goes below the lower cell.

First **Scale To Fill** Second **Aspect Fill**

[image]
I want to use **Aspect Fill** and gain as below:

[image]

I use following to select the image mode

[image]

**My code**

**Cell.m**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
     _img.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
  }
```

**VCUIViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NoticiasDetailImageCell";
        NoticiasDetailImageCell *cell = (NoticiasDetailImageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (NoticiasDetailImageCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.img.image = self.img;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: Did my solution below work for you? If yes, please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to use:

```
image.clipsToBounds = YES;
image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Does it give you the desired results?

Comment: I will check and will inform u

Comment: check the edited question with  below <<<<<use following to select the image mode>>>>>>>>

Comment: I m still getting <<Second Aspect Fill >> as shown in image

Comment: are you doing this in your code or not : image.clipsToBounds = YES;?

Comment: I have used  _img.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; as u mentioned above

Comment: add your code in your question above and show your screenshot of your cell xib. Thanks.

Comment: things is that i have used Aspect Fill in xib of cell no code is requiored for that. and i have try ur code and it wont help out

Comment: Yes, I have read your question in detail and then only answered you. You have confirmed that you are setting clipsToBounds in your code which is also needed. I just asked you to show me that code for the cell (cellForRowAtIndexPath method) where you are setting this property to true for the cell. Without the code, I don't think I can help you. Good luck with finding an answer.

Comment: are you having more than one section?

Comment: Hmm, looking at your code, I think it should work, but one last try you can do is set cell.clipsToBounds=YES In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Try that and let me know if it works?

Comment: Hope to get that in question too